# Re-load groovy files from jar within WAR

Tags: spring, groovy

I have set of groovy files within JAR (rules.jar) and have added this JAR as dependency to WAR (project.war) through Maven. I have done the groovy configuration using Spring and it all works fine and it gets called.

```
<lang:groovy id="primaryScript" script-source="classpath:org/sample/rules/PrimaryScript.groovy"                  refresh-check-delay="5">
</lang:groovy>
```

The issue comes when I change something in Groovy file and it doesn't reflect till I re-build the jar and copy the jar within project.war's WEB-INF/lib.

I want to use the capability of Groovy re-loading and I don't want to keep the groovy within the WAR. Can anyone please help me out here.

I am using JDK 1.8, Groovy 2.4.7 and Tomcat 8 and use Netbeans.

Thanks

Comment: Why did you add the groovy files as a dependency?  When it deploys, the code deployed and read by the server will be compiled groovy classes which are (more or less) just compiled java classes.  There's no need to have groovy files as a dependency.

Comment: Even if I moved the groovy script to project-war and I changed the script, it is not reflecting. I used maven-resources-plugin to copy the groovy script to target folder so that it will not be compiled during build time. Not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: I am using Netbeans 8.0 - I see that groovy within target is not updated when I change the groovy, which I think is the reason the changes are not reflecting. Not sure whether it is Netbeans issue.

Comment: You might want to try Eclipse (ps://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/how-to-configure-hot-deploy-in-eclipse/) or IntelliJ.  I think they are better at Hot Swapping and therefore gives you an update of what your changes are as you are coding.

Comment: No - its not about IDE - I want to know whether we need to write any independent script to move the groovy files so that WAR can run the latest groovy - If yes, what type of scripts can we write ?